# Thread decorated function - is_alive attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading, ethercat

*TLDR: how to check if thread is alive when I used the thread function as a decorator on another function?*

I'm creating a GUI using PyQt6 (other recommendations will be accepted in case its a bad choice).
my issue is when I click the Connect button, I want to verify the connection thread is not running.

i marked with ** what is relevant due to the long code

So I created self.ecMaster attribute in the main *init* and im trying to check if ecConnection is up using is_alive method on which is decorated with @threaded.

i'm getting an error : AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'is_alive'

How should i do it properly?
Thank you

## Main

```
from threading import thread
import pysoem
import ecAPI as ec
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt6.QtCore import *
from PyQt6.QtGui import *

class mainWindow(QMainWindow):
    exitSignal = Signal()  # Define the custom exit signal

    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):        
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.exitSignal.connect(app.quit)
        self.central_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.test_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.modeSignal = ''
        self.operatorSignal = ''
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        self.connectionWindowLayout()
        **self.master = ec.ecMaster()**

def connectButtonClicked(self):
    self.connect_button.clickable = False
    # here i ran into trouble
    **if self.master.ecConnection.is_alive:**              # If thread is active
        self.master.ecConnection.terminate()
        logger.info('Connection thread was already active, terminated')
    logger.info('Starting connection thread')
    **self.master.ecConnection()**                      # Start connection thread
    time.sleep(0.1)  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ModernStyle.apply(app)
    window = mainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

## ecAPI.py

```
import pysoem, logging
from threading import Thread

def threaded(fn):
    # To use as decorator to make a function call threaded 
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        thread = Thread(target=fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        thread.start()
        return thread
    return wrapper

class ecMaster(pysoem.Master):
    def __init__(self):
        self.connectionSignal = 0
        super().__init__()
    
    def findAdapters(self):
        nicName = 'PCIe'            # Change based on PC --- 'PCIe
        network_adapters = pysoem.find_adapters()
        for adapter in network_adapters:
            if nicName in str(adapter[1]):
                networkAdapterID = adapter[0]
                self.open(networkAdapterID)
                logging.info('Found network adapter\n'+str(networkAdapterID))
        return len(network_adapters)>0 # True if found

    @threaded
    def ecConnection(self):
        if self.findAdapters():
            print('Searching for EC devices ... ')
            self.connectionSignal = self.config_init()         # Initilize connection
            if self.slaves:
                print(f'Found {len(self.slave_list)} devices')
                for i,slave in enumerate(self.slaves):
                    # ven = slave.sdo_read(0x1018, 1)
                    print(f'Found Device {slave.name},{slave.id},{slave.man}') #,{slave.sdo_read()}
                    logging.info(f'Found {self.connectionSignal} EC devices')
            else: 
                logging.info('No salves were found')
                print('Slaves not found')
        else:
            logging.warning('No network adapter found')
            print('No network adapter found')
```

Tried to remove wrapper and leave only thread.
searched online.
Expected the function I decorated to have Thread attribute but could't get it right.

Comment: Could it be as simple as `is_alive` is a function not an attribute? i.e. `if self.master.ecConnection.is_alive()`

Comment: Tried both, got an error.     if self.master.ecConnection.is_alive():              # If thread is active
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'is_alive'

Comment: Try `print (self.master.ecConnection)` I suspect this is not an object of type thread as you expect it to be, Can't work out what I'd expect it to be just from reading that code (I don't use decorators very often) but the error message is definitely suggesting such and finding out what it actually is should give you a clue as to where you're going wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found a solution.
`self.master.ecConnection()` isn't a thread but a function. only when running it, it becomes a thread (due to `@threaded` decorator).
therefore I added
`con_thread = self.master.ecConnection()`
and then con_thread was indeed a thread object and I could access `con_thread.is_alive()`